# Why am I keep getting these warning messages in my VS CODE console?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-oauth, source-maps

So below is the exact warning message that I keep seeing when I "npm start" my project. I hope it helps to fix it. I'm also using "firebase" as the data center and "GoogleAuthProvider" for a real-time Login Page, and "react-router-dom@5.2.0" and also "react-chat-engine@7.sm.sm" they are not the latest updates, cuz I'm trying to learn how to upgrade a project that was built by older versions and now needs to revamp it to the latest versions. but the fact is, it has to work even using the older versions, so that I could see something so that I could revamp it to newer ones, cuz they all have been working until recently.
Thank you everyone in advance.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\promise\promise] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\promise\promise] '

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\util\arrayiterator] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\util\arrayiterator] '

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\util\makeiterator] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:es6\util\makeiterator] '

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\defineproperty] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\defineproperty] '

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\global] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\global] '

WARNING in ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\polyfill] ' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\abedi\Desktop\React Tutorial\chating-app\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\ [synthetic:util\polyfill]
```

I tried other solutions in the Stack Overflow already and none of them worked for me, I'm not sure why, I'm kind of new to this, so, but I hope I can fix this so I can get done with it and move to other projects and practices.